# How to simulate an online reservation in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have in my database something like this:

```
public partial class Reservation
{
    public int ReservationID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Data { get; set;}// this has the date and the hour
    public string User_Id { get; set; }
    public string Service { get; set; }
}
```

In order to make a new reservation, the client has to introduce the date, the service and the hour. I want to make a `ComboBox` with the hours which are available for the date, that was already selected. I was thinking of making something like this: a list with all hours in general, to query the database and select the hours which have already been reserved. Then to subtract from all the hours, the ones which have been reserved and the result will be in that `ComboBox`. What I've done until now is an `IEnumerable SelectListItem` with all hours from 10 am to 6 pm and a query which gives me the reserved hours, but I don't know if it works. I assumed that "date" is a parameter selected previously.

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> occupied = db.Reservation.Where(x => x.Data == date).Select(
    m => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = m.Data.ToShortTimeString(),
        Text = m.Data.ToShortTimeString()
    }
);
```

If this is correct, what should I do next ? If not, please suggest an alternative method.

Comment: Return the occupied list to the view as a model and then use it with DropDownListFor

Comment: But what I need to return to the view is only the available hours for the selected date .. which means that it is a subtraction between all hours and the occupied hours for that date. How can I do that ?

Comment: That wont work as you are comparing full date that will include seconds, you only want to compare date and hour

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i did for one of our project:

1. Generate A collection of object `List<OrderSchedulerViewModel>` where OrderSchedulerViewModel (int OrderId, dataTime Time, enum Status). `enum Status{Free, Reserved, Unavailable}`
2. Get Orders in database from today date and in a foreach cycle fill up your List with orders that already exist.
3. Display to Admin/User a table where he can view all time available and give him a way to just click avalaible time. Onclick just open a popup where he can fill order data and save.

[image]